# Does F# have free functions?

Tags: c#, math, f#, function

Does every function has to be inside a type like in C#? Or does F# has free functions?

Also what about functions I have seen all over some F# code like, cos, sin, etc. Are they calls to Math.Cos, Math.Sin?

Also why did they provide cos, sin, etc like that instead of Math.Cos, Math.Sin?

Answer (score 7):

F# can have [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229(VS.100).aspx) scoped in [modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221(VS.100).aspx) (instead of classes).

The CLR implements these, internally, as:

> as a common language runtime (CLR) class that has only static members

They look like "free functions" within the scope of a module.

Comment: Thanks Reed. Do you know why they chose to do that for math functions. Or you mean there is no type.method in F#? Everything is function (object)?

Comment: @Joan: F# has a *long* heritage. Those stuff are inherited from OCaml. F# does have method calls like C# too.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad. Last question: why is CLR is configured so it can't have true free functions but has to fake it with a static class? Just wondering.

Comment: CLR actually has support for free functions. Not sure why F# compiler is "faking" them - probably to implement modules.

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic: Do you have a reference showing the CLR's "free function" support?  My understanding is that the CLR does not have support for this, and requires "free functions" to be wrapped into a static class in the CLR.

Comment: @Reed - The CLR allows "global" static methods to be placed on the special top-level `<Module>` type, which is a type defined in each module which has no base class and which has special rules for metadata merging.

Answer (score 7):

As Reed mentioned, functions can be defined within modules a la other ML languages, but they can also be defined on types like other .NET languages (and in fact modules are also compiled to classes).  Within F#, modules can be `open`ed to access the functions without having to use the module name each time, and modules are automatically created on a per-file basis if they aren't explicitly declared.

As to why there are separate `cos`, etc. functions instead of merely relying on .NET's built-in `Math.Cos`, etc., there are probably several reasons:

1. Uniformity: `cos` looks much more idiomatic in F# than calling the static method `System.Math.Cos`.
2. Static constraints: `cos` doesn't just work on `float`s in F#, it also works on `float32`s and on any type which exposes a static `Cos` method, so you can create your own types to which the `cos` function can be applied.

I'd guess that truly free functions aren't allowed because there are many .NET languages which don't expose convenient access to them, so using them would present a barrier to cross-language interoperability.  The CLR itself does support free functions, and some languages such as C++/CLI do use them, but most languages compile functions into classes (even if that's not how it looks from a source code perspective, as in F#).

Comment: Another reason is that `cos` can be implemented with F#-style arguments rather than tupled arguments, allowing for partial function application, which `Math.Cos` doesn't support.

Comment: @Joel - can you expand on what you mean?  Like all one-argument .NET functions, `System.Math.Cos` can be used as an `_ -> _`, just like `cos`.  If it took multiple arguments, then you would be correct.

Comment: Thanks kvb. So F# cos is another method other than Math.Cos? Where is the full name for F# cos then? CommonInvisibleStaticClass.Cos? Or the cos has been defined for everything in F# like you said.

Comment: @Joan - it's in the Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators module, which is opened by default (so that all functions within it can be accessed without having to qualify them with the module name).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754%28VS.100%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340316%28VS.100%29.aspx.

Comment: Cos was a bad example - I wasn't paying attention to the actual method. Generally speaking, if there is more than one parameter, I would rather use a `max` with a signature of `int -> int -> int` than `Math.Max` with a signature of `(int * int) -> int`. As one more reason to make functional aliases for things that are already built into the framework.

Answer (score 4):

@Reed's answer is good.  I just wanted to add that in F# you can 'open' modules so that module-bound functions can be called in an unqualified way, and that is where various 'top level' functions and operators come from, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754(VS.100).aspx

That is, F# is still subject to the CLR mechanisms, which means that every function must be in a class, but F# modules map to static classes on the CLR, modules can be 'opened' to provide the functions at the top level, and a handful of modules are 'auto-opened' so that the most common/convenient functions are available right away.

Having a variety of common functions available is very useful for scripting or interactive sessions, where you don't want to have to open a bunch of namespaces or spell out in 15 characters "System.Math.Cos" just to compute a cosine.

Comment: Thanks so I am right to assume this can only be applied to static functions? Like you can't open instance functions to be top level free functions, right?

Comment: Yes, it can only be applied to functions in modules (which happen to be static).

Answer (score 3):

Joan,

Rather than all these questions about which features F# supports or does not support, maybe you'd be better served to start with a book on F#.  Consider these two resources as a starting point:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming

And also:

[The F# Survival Guide](http://www.ctocorner.com/fsharp/book/default.aspx)

There's also Chris Smith's book which is an excellent introductory text.

[Programming F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596153643)

Maybe you want to read them and work through them and then you can ask more directed questions.  Just an idea.